# Using IDA pro decompiler in Ghidra

Tags: ida, ghidra

Is it possible to use IDA pro decompiler in Ghidra ?
I know the opposite is possible.

Answer (score 2):

The Hex-Rays decompiler heavily relies on IDA for disassembly and other analysis so it’s unlikely it can be made to work without reimplementing (most of) IDA. Besides, it would be against the license.

You can, however, migrate your Ghidra project to IDA and then use the decompiler.